# Django Query - Prefetch filter based on query data?

Tags: python, django

Im trying to filter a prefetch based on its parent query object, is this possible? hopefully the below example explains.

live link type from SiteData and circuit type from Circuits use the same child model.

so for example if the live link type is 'Fibre' I want to prefetch only the circuit that has the circuit_type of 'Fibre'. each site can have many circuits but I only want the live one at this moment

This is the query:

```
conn_stats = SiteData.objects.all()
    .exclude(site_type__site_type='Factory') \
    .exclude(site_type__site_type='Data Centre') \
    .Prefetch(
        'circuits_set',
        queryset=Circuits.objects.filter(SiteData.objects.live_link_type.circuit_type)
        )
)
```

these are the models:

```
class CircuitTypes(models.Model):
    circuit_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    monitor_priority = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Monitoring Priority", blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Circuit Types"
        verbose_name_plural = "Circuit Types"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.circuit_type

class SiteData(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    site_type = models.ForeignKey(SiteTypes, verbose_name="Site Type", \
                on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_live = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is this a live site?")
    live_link_type = models.ForeignKey(CircuitTypes, verbose_name="Link Type", \
                on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=1)
    live_link_preference = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    live_link_query_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

class Circuits(models.Model):
    site_data = models.ForeignKey(SiteData, verbose_name="Site", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    order_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Order No")
    expected_install_date = models.DateField()
    install_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    circuit_type = models.ForeignKey(CircuitTypes, verbose_name="Circuit Type", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot do what you ask with a single queryset.

If the number of `CircuitTypes` is small, you can consider constructing a queryset for each type of circuit:

```
circuit_types = CircuitType.object.all()
for circuit_type in circuit_types:
    prefetch = Prefetch('circuits_set',
                        queryset=Circuits.objects.filter(
                            circuit_type=circuit_type)
    conn_stats = SiteData.objects.filter(live_link_type=circuit_type) \
        .exclude(site_type__site_type='Factory') \
        .exclude(site_type__site_type='Data Centre') \
        .prefetch_related(prefetch)
```

If there are many circuit types and this is prohibitive then you can perhaps add a boolean `active` field to `Circuits` and update its value when changing each `SiteData.live_link_type`. That way you would be able to query only for active `Circuits` directly:

```
prefetch = Prefetch('circuits_set',
                    queryset=Circuits.objects.filter(active=True)
conn_stats = SiteData.objects.all() \
    .exclude(site_type__site_type='Factory') \
    .exclude(site_type__site_type='Data Centre') \
    .prefetch_related(prefetch)
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe youre right, I will move the active field from the the site data model to the circuits model instead, that should solve the issues